# Slow calculation of sum of primes for large datasets

Tags: java

My program that calculates the sum of primes is very slow for very large nth term. Please how do I optimize the processing time of my program? The fastest program will be appreciated and the reason why mine is slow for large sets of data. Thanks.

Here's the Java program:

```
 public class SumOfPrimes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primeNumber(2000000);
    }

    public static void primeNumber(int nth) {
        int counter = 0, i = 2;
        while(i>=2) {
            if(isPrime(i)) {
                counter += i;
            }
            i++;
            if(i == nth) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        boolean prime = true;
        int i;
        for(i= 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                prime = false;
                for (int j = 3; j * j < n; j += 2) {
                    if (n % j == 0) prime = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }

 }
```

Comment: This should be on [codereview.se] since this is a working solution

Comment: By the way, you don't need to check every value `from 2 to n`, but `from 2 to n/2`, every value after that won't matter

Comment: Thanks, just knowing this now. So do I move it, how do I move it?

Comment: Thanks for that observation, that will halve the processing time.

Comment: @optimalresource I've flagged your question for moderator attention, as they're the only ones who can move your question. It might take a while for  it to be moved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take note of that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be your isPrime function-

```
bool isPrime (int number) { 
    if (number < 2) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i=3; (i*i) <= number; i+=2) {
        if (number % i == 0 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is by far the best optimized version of the code. Reason is that we have less looping in the for loop. I applied it in my program and the program  is super fast. No doubt my accepted answer for now. Everyone has contributed beautifully too.

Answer (score 8):

Well, it's unclear why you have an inner for loop in your `isPrime`. Removing it will save much time.

Besides, once you find that `n` is not prime, you should return immediately. Either break out of the loop, or just return `false`.

Another optimization would be not to test all the number until `i < n`. It's enough to test until `i * i <= n`.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ow yeah, square root of n ... not half of n... I knew it was perfect... could remember the exact limit

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, it saved a lot more time, but the program is still incredibly slow. I mean for large dataset. I tried running 2,000,000

Answer (score 4):

Remember primes you have found, and only test them.

Remove the inner loop.

Test 2, 3, then all odds.

Something like...

```
public boolean isPrime( ArrayList<Long> primes, long n ){
    for( Long t : primes ){
        if( n % t == 0 ){
            return false;
        }
        if( t * t > n )return true;
    }
    return true;
}
public void sumOfPrimes()
{

    ArrayList<Long> primes = new ArrayList<Long>();
    long n;
    double count = 0;
    for( n = 2; n < 2000000; n++ ){
        if( isPrime( primes, n ) ){
            primes.add( n );
            count += n;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of Lambda for dynamic functional referencing and streams for optimized performance with inbuilt filter conditions.

```
public static boolean isPrime(final int number) {
    return IntStream.range(2,(long) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number + 1))).noneMatch(x -> number % x == 0);
}
```

Comment: The dataset I talked about is 2000000, not up to a billion, so int is still very much okay for the isPrime function. I think there's nothing wrong with the data type for values less than 2,147,483,647, which my program demands

Comment: Agreed.
Modified working example for integer values

Also the logic for checking prime for a large number, is only iterating to a maximum of square root of the number.
i.e Time complexity of log(n) which is optimum

and since we are using an integer stream, due to lazy loading there is less computational load on the processor

Answer (score 0):

Putting together all the answers to my question above, my program has been re-written and it is much faster for very large datasets.

```
 public class SumOfPrimes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primeNumber(2000000);
    }

    public static void primeNumber(int nth) {
        int i = 2;
        long  counter = 0;
        while(i>=2) {
            if(isPrime(i)) {
                counter += i;
            }
            i++;
            if(i == nth) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

public static boolean isPrime (int n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i=3; (i*i) <= n; i+=2) {
        if (n % i == 0 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

@aega's solution for the isPrime function did the trick. Now 2 million datasets can be calculated for less than 2 secs.

Comment: Test only the primes like what mksteve said, can complete the calculation in less than half second.

Answer (score 0):

We no need to test from 1 to n, even 3 to n/2 or 3 to sqrt(n) is also too much for testing for a bigger number.

To make the testing the least, we can only test n with the previous prime that have been found up to sqrt(n), like what mksteve has mentioned.

```
static List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

static boolean isPrime (int number) { 
    if (number < 2) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false;

    int limit = (int) Math.sqrt(number);

    for (i : primes) {
        if (i > limit) break;
        if (number % i == 0 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void primeNumber(int nth) {
    int i = 2;
    long  counter = 0;
    while(i <= nth) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            counter += i;
            primes.add(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A faster program will be to store the generated prime numbers in an array and use only those elements for divisibility check. The number of iterations will reduce dramatically. An element of self-learning is there in this.

I don't have time right now. But, when I'm free, will write a java code to implement this.